# Do I need to pay Estimated Taxes on Qualified dividend income if I fall in the 0% Long-Term Capital Gains tax bracket?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, estimated-taxes, qualified-dividend

Basically I make ~$21000 in income from work, and $1000 in dividends. So, being below $40k in income, I technically owe 0% on the qualified dividend income, but I'm not sure if I pay the IRS and get a refund for the full amount paid, or hold on to everything and just report it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to give the IRS an interest-free loan, hold on to everything, and file accordingly.
If your situation doesn't change significantly later in the year, you will not owe taxes, so you are fine.

Comment: Ok. I was just worried they wanted to hold the money until I filed end of year taxes. TY.